# QTreeView, how to call an action when mouse hovers over a row?

Tags: qt, qt5, qtreeview, qstandarditemmodel

I am using C++ Qt5. Currently I have a QStandardItemModel being displayed as a QTreeView with multiple rows and columns. I am aware of using setStyleSheet(), but that just seems to change the color of the row. What I'm looking for is when the mouse hovers over a row, a function is called which I can then use to manipulate my game.

Comment: Could you explain me better, what data do you need from the row or do you only want that function to be called when you change rows?

Comment: I'm looking for a unique id from each row/col and as I hover over the row/col, a function is called with the unique id from the row & col.

Comment: you could give more detail about the ID besides providing a [mcve], to track the hover you could use the mouseMoveEvent method of QTreeView or the editorEvent on a delegate. Your current question is partly clear, but partly misleading, so we need more details.

Comment: I agree with @eyllanesc, I would overload `mouseMoveEvent()`. May be, it's worth to mention [`QTreeView::indexAt()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#indexAt) for this which _Returns the model index of the item at the viewport coordinates point._

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use delegate (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-stardelegate-example.html) and QStyle::State_MouseOver to check if mouse over a row.
You should override ***paint*** method.

```
void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const {
    if(index.row() == 2 && (option.state & QStyle::State_MouseOver)) {
        painter->fillRect(option.rect, Qt::blue);
    } else {
        QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, option, index);
    }
}
```

Comment: `setMouseTracking(true)` must be called first for the itemview, otherwise, the `QStyle::State_MouseOver ` will not be set in the `option.state`.